# Equivalence classes and writing sets - Quotient Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, relations

I need to write the quotient set of this relation:
Over the set: $\mathbb{N}$
$ aRb \leftrightarrow (2 \nmid a \cdot b ~ \vee a=b)$

So the equivalence sets are: $\{1,3,5,7, \dots\}$ and all the singletons: $\{2\}, \{3\} , \dots $

Does this count as a "well written" (and true?) answer (final answer only):

$\{a : 2 \nmid a \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{ \{a\} : 2 \mid a \in \mathbb{N} \}$

Because I am not sure of how to write it in a formal mathematical way..

Thank you!

Comment: Your final answer is correct; your preliminary one is not, because it’s only the even singletons that are equivalence classes.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott is it every natural number? but the odd ones are already in the first set (the odds..) no? thanks!

Comment: Sorry I did not read that right! Thanks, so it's only the even *because* the odd ones are already in the odd's set? thanks

Comment: Yes, that’s right: the odd ones in the first set.

Comment: Thank you sir! :-)

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: Probably you mean $\{\{a : 2 \nmid a \in \mathbb{N}\} \}\cup \{ \{a\} : 2 \mid a \in \mathbb{N} \}$ instead of $\{a : 2 \nmid a \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{ \{a\} : 2 \mid a \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

Comment: @jens schwaiger why ? I wrote union there , it should be fine, no?

Comment: The quotient set is a set of sets, namely the set of equivalence classes. And $ \{a : 2 \nmid a \in \mathbb{N}\} $ is one of them.